# Tool to export GitHub issues with comments into a single HTML page?

Tags: html, git, github, kindle

I would like to read all my project issues in my Kindle Reader. Is there any tool to collect issues (with comments) into a single HTML/PDF page so it can be exported to Kindle?

[Related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369365/how-can-i-export-github-issues-to-excel) provide only JSON, CSV (or similar structured) output without comments.